How can I give Text a button appearance in SwiftUI?
I'm trying to build a NavigationStack that has Buttons instead of links.
While I know how to make Text look like a Button, am unsure as to how to give it the changing appearance look of a Button when it is pressed.
The code below is using two @State vars so that I can reduce the fake Button's size.  But with all the different .onTapX permutations, I can not find the correct one to modify the @State vars when the button is being pressed down.
Thank you
import SwiftUI

struct MainMenuWithStack: View {
    
    @State var butW : CGFloat = 150
    @State var butH : CGFloat = 75
    @State var curTG = "--"
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationStack{
            
            VStack(spacing: 5) {
                
                NavigationLink(destination: HomePage()){
                    Text("Home")
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .font(.title)
                        .frame(width: butW, height: butH)
                        .background(.blue)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


#Preview {
    MainMenuWithStack()
}


Search for "SwiftUI ButtonStyle"

Try .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)

@BenzyNeez But I'm not using real buttons here. Don't I have to monitor user interactions and change the faux-button myself?  Also, I was under impressions that I could not use buttons in a navigation stack.  Obviously if I am wrong about that I would love to know

The modifier .buttonStyle can be applied to a NavigationLink in just the same way as it can be applied to a Button.
The following comes quite close to the styling in your example:
NavigationStack{
    VStack(spacing: 5) {
        NavigationLink(destination: HomePage()) {
            Text("Home")
                .font(.title)
                .padding()
        }
    }
    .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
}

You can also implement your own custom ButtonStyle if you want to encapsulate all the styling in one place. This makes it possible to apply different styling when the button is pressed, by inspecting the value of the property ButtonStyleConfiguration.isPressed.
